# Creating Swap Partition

Tags: partitioning, swap, preinstallation

Hello I am very new user of Linux. I am going to install Ubuntu 14.0.4 and have two questions:

1. The partition in which the Ubuntu will be installed, what would be the partition type primary or logical?
2. I also want to know that what would be the partition type of the Swap area? Logical or Primary?

Answer (score 0):

Linux in general (and Ubuntu specifically) have no problems booting from a logical partition, therefor its safe to use these for all partitions you choose to create. The Ubuntu installer will always create logical partitions anyways and its not a good idea to override this behavior since you can only create up to 4 primary partitions.

(The only operating system still in use today that has problems with booting from logical partitions is Windows XP by-the-way)

Answer (score 0):

The main thing to remember is that (for some old inherited stupid reason), hard disks can only hold 4 primary partitions. To overcome the problem that in some situations, more partitions are needed, they invented logical partitions (which are basically logical divisions within a primary partition).

Linux can handle logical partitions, not all Windows versions can.

I barely ever use more than 4 partitions on a drive, so personally, I don't use logical partitions... but there's really nothing wrong with them.